# Express header has no cookies, depending on the path

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, cookies, request

I'm using express.js. I have an app with two controllers for handling requests:
/auth & /posts

I have added token authorization to set the Authorization cookie.

The problem is, when I make a request to /posts, the request goes through authMiddleware, which tries to validate the cookie, but cannot access it because property 'cookie' doesn't exist on request.header, despite me sending cookies through.

What's even weirder is that it works just fine when I make a request on the /auth route, in that case request.header.cookie is populated appropriately.

Controllers for both routes don't differ that much, they pretty much follow the same format of having a path property and a constructor which initializes the routes

```
class PostsController implements Controller {
  public path = '/posts';
  public router = express.Router();

  constructor() {
    this.initializeRoutes();
  }

  public initializeRoutes() {
    this.router.get(this.path, this.getAllPosts);
    this.router.get(this.path + '/:id', this.getPostById);
    this.router.all(this.path + '/*', authMiddleware)
    .patch(this.path + '/:id', this.updatePostById)
    .delete(this.path + '/:id', this.deletePostById);
    this.router.post(this.path, authMiddleware, this.createAPost);
  }
```

```
class AuthenticationController implements Controller {
    public path = '/auth';
    public router = express.Router();
    private user = userModel;

    constructor() {
        this.initializeRoutes();
    }

    private initializeRoutes() {
        this.router.post(`${this.path}/register`, this.registration);
        this.router.post(`${this.path}/login`, this.login);
    }
```

```
private initializeMiddlewares() {
      this.app.use('/*', (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(req.headers);  // returns headers with cookie for /auth only
        const cookies = req.headers.cookie.split(';'); // fails here on /posts
        const parsedCookies = {};
        cookies.forEach( pair => {
          const key = pair.split('=')[0];
          const value = pair.split('=')[1];
          if(key && value){
            parsedCookies[key] = value;
          }     
        })
        req.cookies = parsedCookies;
        console.log(req.cookies);
        next();
      })
      this.app.use(bodyParser.json());

    }
```

I'd of course like to access the cookie property regardless of the route.

I've even tried not using either of the controllers, but this problem persists, it seems to be solely related to the route I'm making requests to, which really doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

When creating the cookie with Authorization, omitting the Path parameter made it default to the current path (which is /auth). Changed that to / and that made the cookie accessible for different routes.

```
private createCookie(tokenData: TokenData) {
        return `Authorization=${tokenData.token}; HttpOnly; Max-Age=${tokenData.expiresIn}; Path=/`;
    }
}
```